Multiple hugo sites per build, with different config?
My actual use case is to have a noscript site, and a heavily styled site, each with a different subdomain. E.g noscr.example.com and pretty.example.com. They share the same content and page bundle structure, just different styling.
With multilingual support from Hugo, it is able to generate multiple sites in different directories in the publishDir.
Is there a way to do this but with different configuration? Such as applying a different theme for each directory in publishDir. Or just different site variable? Then templating could be conditionally applied.
Might it be just just simpler to run a shell script for each hugo build, setting a site variable in the arguments?
Edit: Solution using a Makefile
In a Makefile I could have:
all:
  hugo --environment s1
  hugo --environment s2
  hugo --environment s3

and have config directories:
s1/ s2/ s3/ in config/
each with a hugo.toml file.
These hugo files can mount a theme, or set a parameter to be used in template files.
Now the main issue is sharing of resources.
It will copy all the assets to each sx/ directory in public/. If i'm using webGL and have lots of assets this gets troublesome.

Have a look at the module mounts. You can define a different one in each config file. They could all point to a shared resources directory, or have their own separate directory. By using assets/ instead of static/, only those needed will be published. https://gohugo.io/hugo-modules/configuration/#module-configuration-mounts

Thanks @Jeremie, Ive had a good look. Still i'm not quite sure how module mounting can prevent copying of the files. It doesn't matter how I set the mounting of assets because hugo copies it over to each sx/ anyway. Same with static/. My thoughts right now are to use symbolic links. Styling I use resources.ExecuteAsTemplate which however gernerates a file still for each site.

As you pointed out, you can use the different languages of the multilingual mode to 'fake' different sites. With multilingual mode, you are not restricted to standard language codes 'en', 'es', 'fr', and there is not a requirement to have the same content architecture for each language.
However, there is no other option available. A very similar question has already been asked on the Gohugo forum and answered by bep, the lead developer.

The above isn’t physically possible (as in: No framework could support
the above).


Thank you for your insight. I am not restricted to using a single process of hugo server like in the forum post. See my edit for a try at a solution.
